# How to remove Docker images created today?

Tags: docker

How to remove Docker images created today and only today ?

The documentation tells you how to delete images  before, but not after some date
https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in opposite to the `until` filter, but you could parse the output of `docker image ls --format=json` command to find images created today; e.g:

```
docker image ls --format=json |
  jq -r --arg today "$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" -s '.[]|select(.CreatedAt|split(" ")[0] == $today)|"\(.Repository):\(.Tag)"'
```

To actually remove the image, you could pipe the output to `xargs docker image rm`:

```
docker image ls --format=json |
  jq -r --arg today "$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" -s '.[]|select(.CreatedAt|split(" ")[0] == $today)|"\(.Repository):\(.Tag)"'
  xargs docker image rm
```

Just wrap that up in a shell script; maybe something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

target=today

while getopts d: ch; do
    case $ch in
    d)  target=$OPTARG
        ;;

    *)  exit 2
        ;;
    esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

docker image ls --format=json |
    jq -r --arg today "$(date -d "$target" +%Y-%m-%d)" -s '.[]|select(.CreatedAt|split(" ")[0] == $today)|"\(.Repository):\(.Tag)"' |
    xargs -r docker image rm
```

Stick this in your `$PATH` with a useful name (maybe `ddi` for "date delete image") and you can delete images created today like this:

```
ddi
```

Or images created yesterday:

```
ddi -d yesterday
```

Or images created on a specific date:

```
ddi -d 2023-11-21
```

Or any other expression supported by `date`:

```
ddi -d 'last year'
```